# Super column families in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Help me understand the section [i don't understand this]
I read again and again , still can't get it

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/65/Super_column_family_(data_store).png

[i understand this]
Where a row in a column family holds a collection of name/value pairs, the super column family holds subcolumns, where subcolumns are named groups of columns. So the address of a value in a regular column family is a row key pointing to a column name pointing to a value,

[i don't understand this]
while the address of a value in a column family of type “super” is a row key pointing to a column name pointing to a subcolumn name pointing to a value. Put slightly differently, a row in a super column family still contains columns, each of which then contains subcolumns.

Comment: From cassandra definitive guide !!

Comment: ok if i get it correctly, 
The section i understand, talks about address of "Super column name" in the diagram.
Andy what i don't understand is the one that talks about address of "Super column family" in the diagram. Am i correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supercolumns have been deprecated for years.  Some modern data modeling resources include DataStax's [introduction to data modeling in Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/ddl/ddl_anatomy_table_c.html) and Patrick McFadin's three-part series:

1. [The Data Model is Dead; Long live the Data Model](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px6U2n74q3g)
2. [Become a Super Modeler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qphhxujn5Es)
3. [The World's Next Top Data Model](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJlsOZVGwM&list=PLqcm6qE9lgKJzVvwHprow9h7KMpb5hcUU&index=11)

Comment: Ok..looks like i need a updated book for cassandra 2.0
Can you please suggest some

Comment: This book will be out in two months: http://www.amazon.com/Practical-Cassandra-Developers-Addison-Wesley-Analytics/dp/032193394X

Comment: Until then, stick with the docs: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/webhelp/index.html